# Bacon.js Maximum Call Stack Exceeded

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

I'm trying to produce a stream similar to `Bacon.fromPoll` for `requestAnimationFrame`

Why does the following code produce a "*Maximum call stack exceeded*" error?

```
function rafSequence() {
    var raf = Bacon.fromCallback(function(callback) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            callback(Date.now());
        });
    });
    return raf.merge(raf.flatMap(rafSequence));
}

rafSequence().log();
```

I thought `merge()` would garbage collect when one of the 2 streams threw a `Bacon.End` (the `raf` in `raf.merge(...)`. So why does it error?

UPDATE:
I have been able to implement a working version as follows:

```
Bacon.repeat(() => Bacon.fromCallback(requestAnimationFrame));
```

I am still interested why `merge()` isn't cleaning up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current Bacon.js implementation (0.6.x) all "infinite" sequences based on recursion are bound to fail, because at each step, the "stream stack" gets deeper. I'm sure there is a way to optimize the implementation to cope better with this kind of constructs, but it's far from trivial.

For your particular case, a `fromGenerator` method would make your implementation simpler. There's already related code in [this commit](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/commit/82e860f74ced4a0a2782b06a546bdc9924e321dc), if you're interested. I suggest you use Github Issues in case you're interested in getting this fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to take a look into it when I get a chance and open an issue.